# Rails: How to make cancan work on each object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

user.rb

```
def has_delete_role? name
  roles.each do |n|
    return true if n == name
  end
end
```

ability.rb

```
if user.has_delete_role? :business_delete
  can :destroy, Business
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<% if can? :destroy, @business %>
  <%= link_to 'delete', business_path(@business.id), method: :delete%>
<% end %>
```

This piece of code allow user who has the authority to access delete button. Here if a user has authority, he can access delete buttons of all objects.
 EX: Business has 10 objects id = 1 to id = 10, user can access all of 10 delete buttons if he has the authority
 
But now I want to set the authority base on object.
EX: Buisness also 1 to 10,  user can only see button 2 and 5 because there is a field in user data table called auth_ids [], it stores [2,5]

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
can :destroy, Business, id: user.auth_ids
```

Comment: I followed your solution, but got an error like this The can? and cannot? call cannot be used with a raw sql 'can' definition.

Comment: Hi, this time no error happens, however it causes cancan not working, for example, auth_ids is [1,2], but I can access all 1 to 10

Comment: gem 'cancancan', '~> 1.15'

Comment: Hey...sorry...I found that I did manage all inside ability....your edited solution totally works for me. Sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a condition, something similar to the guide here: https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities

```
can :destroy, Business, Business.where('id = ?', user.auth_ids)
```

Comment: I followed your solution, but got an error like this `The can? and cannot? call cannot be used with a raw sql 'can' definition.`